# Why don't all review categories have counters?

Tags: feature-request, reviewing

There is a nice counter for suggested edits.  It's great!  Why not have counters for first answers, low quality posts, first questions, and late answers?

[image]

Comment: Most likely because the suggested edits counter is already maintained for 10kers and mods to see on all pages of the website (you will see it by your badge count in the top bar), while the others aren't.

Comment: @badp - My main question is why does suggested edits deserve one, but not the others.  They feel inferior. It would be nice for sub-10kers to see the breakdown.

Comment: whooooops typo.

Comment: If you're requesting that this be added, you might want to take it to [metase].

Comment: Note that there are almost never 0 items on the other tabs on Stack Overflow (in fact, the numbers are often quite large) and only the number of suggested edits is guaranteed to be the same for everyone, so it's possible the utility of indicators on the other tabs were ruled out based on the cost/benefit of those points.

Comment: @TimStone Almost never 0? Last time I checked the review backlog on SO was hundreds of thousands of posts deep. Our backlog here is a bit less daunting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the new review system renders this question moot.